# @XmlAnnotation to solve "A cycle is detected in the object graph." exception

Tags: java, netbeans, jax-ws, netbeans-7, xmltransient

I am trying to implement a solution which have relational database logic between tables Document and DocumentField. This solution will be used as a web service and will be consumed by a client. 
I was getting the following exception from my web service client:

```
Exception: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: com.bla.bla.ws.Document@115cfb9 -> com.bla.bla.ws.DocField@94e6ee -> com.bla.bla.ws.Document@115cfb9]
```

In order to solve this problem I added @XmlTransient annotation:

Document:

```
@Entity(name = "Document")
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT", schema = "DOCUMENT")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Document extends BasicObject implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = -5274375009324738532L;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="doc") 
    @XmlTransient   
    private List<DocField> extraInfo;
```

DocField:

```
public class DocField extends BasicObject implements Serializable { 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7403660716697161123L;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="DOC_ID")   
   @XmlTransient
   private Document doc;
```

But now I can not reach my docField from the client with this code snippet:

```
Document testDoc = new Document ();
DocField testDocField = new DocField();
testDoc.getDocField.add(testDocField);
```

I think I misunderstood some points in this kind of solution. Can anyone provide some explanation about this? Or any external resource?

Comment: When I ran into a similar exception it was because I forgot to close the `EntityManager` (unless you do have a cyclic reference)

Comment: No, that's not the case.. Thanks for the comment anyway..